# Perl mongo->collection count using '$in' operator

Tags: perl, mongodb, count, operators, mongo-collection

I was wondering if it was possible to use the "in" operator as you can from the mongo shell, using the perl MongoDB::Collection module.  I have tried a number of things, but haven't quite got the result I am expecting.  I've check the docs and other posts on stackoverflow but can't seem to find anything specifically about this, unless I am overlooking something.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

The count query I am running via the mongo shell is

```
mongo:PRIMARY> db.getCollection("Results").count( { TestClass : "TestClass", TestMethod : { $in: ["method1" , "method2", "method3"] } })
181605
```

I have tried this a few different ways passing the list as an array or hash-refs or pre-building a string...

```
my $count = $mongo->{collection}->count({
                            'TimeStamp'     => { '$gt' => $ft, '$lt' => $tt },
                            'TestClass'     => $TestClass,
                            'TestMethod'    => { '$in' => [$whitelist->methods] },
                            'Result'        => $result
                    });
```

Where Dumping `$whitelist->methods` is

```
$VAR1 = {
      'method1' => 1,
      'method2' => 1,
      'method3' => 1
    };
```

I've looked high and low for an answer, does anyone know if the driver is currently capable of using the $in operator like this?  Looping through the returned methods from a previous query and adding up the results will require more code.

The only other stack overflow post I have seen about the $in operator was this [$in mongoDB operator with _id in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616746/in-mongodb-operator-with-id-in-perl/14616856#14616856) recommending using http://api.mongodb.org/perl/current/MongoDB/OID.html but don't think that is relevant in my example as looks more to do with ID's.

Any help or discussion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your $whitelist->methods is a hashref, not an array. What happens when you write `[keys %{$whitelist->methods}]` instead?

Comment: Awesome that seems to work and produce a result!  thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Would you like me to post this as answer so you'll be able to accept it? )

Comment: Sure all seems valid to me, i'm just double checking some query numbers to make sure, but looks like I was just passing the data in the wrong way as you say.

Comment: Numbers add up with manual querying so happy to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$in` clause expects its value to be an array reference, but you supply a hashref (as Dumper's output shows) into it. The easiest way to turn the latter into the former is to apply `keys` function:

```
# ...
'TestMethod'    => { '$in' => [keys %{$whitelist->methods}] }
```

... or just `[keys $whitelist->methods]`, if you're using Perl 5.14+, as ...

> starting with Perl 5.14, `keys` can take a scalar EXPR, which must
>   contain a reference to an unblessed hash or array

.